# int counter inside OncollisionEnter not increasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

THis is my bullet.cs which is attached to bullet instance which is non-existant at the start of the game. It instanciate when mouse is clicked.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Bullet instance;
    public float bulletSpeed = 2f;
    public float destroyTime = 2.5f;
    public int damageAmount = 10;
    public GameObject explosion;
    private int hitCount = 0;
    int fuck = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject, destroyTime);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float distance = bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime; // distance to move this frame
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(distance, 0f, 0f); // movement vector
        transform.Translate(movement); // move the object
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("destroyer"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Astroid"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); // Destroy the bullet
            Destroy(collision.gameObject); // destroy the asteroid
            hitCount += 5;
            
            //UIManager.instance.UpdateScoreText(hitCount);
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }


    public int GetHitCount()
    {
        return hitCount;
    }
}
```

This is my UImanager script. It is attached to canvas

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text scoreText;
    public TMP_Text highScoreText;

    private int score = 0;
    
    public static UIManager instance;
    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        
    }


    public void UpdateScoreText( int hitCount)
    {
        score = hitCount;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
}
```

the `Debug.log` counter works but the hitCount just stays the same.
[image]

Can someone give me an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Each bullet has its own `hitCount` and you destroy the bullet gameobject when you increment `hitCount` - so there is no logical way that `hitCount` can ever be greater than 5

Comment: So. Bullet doesnt call update score text. And ui manager never gets hit count. Ar what point was something suppose to tell or ask or find out how that hit count had changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation:
You are currently destroying the `gameObject` the script is on so *all subsequent logs are from OTHER bullets*. As it stands, each one has their own hitCount (because this is an [instance variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable)) set initially to zero and on colliding they are incremented to 5, print and the object then ceases to exist. The member variable hitCount is not persistent and not shared between them.

Consider storing the hitCount in an object that is not destroyed in this way and/or has a longer lifetime.

Some extra help:
To clarify, the only Log function is currently commented out and also is printing out a different variable. I assume this was not the case when you generated the output. On Stack overflow make sure your code reflects its state when the other artifacts such as output were generated. Also, consider eliminating the other variable because it does not perform a relevant function and then try logging hitCount again.

From there I would also suggest you add more information to the logs to describe what is being printed instead of leaving it as a number without context.

e.g.:

```
Debug.Log($"Hit an asteroid.\n{nameof(hitCount)} is currently {hitCount},");
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. And i will definitely follow your advice for generating log for next time.

Answer (score 1):

the count is sent to UIManager with

```
//UIManager.instance.UpdateScoreText(hitCount);
```

which I assume is commented out for testing of some kind. The real issue is in UIManager.

change

```
public void UpdateScoreText( int hitCount)
{
    score = hitCount;
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
}
```

to

```
public void UpdateScoreText( int hitCount)
{
    score += hitCount;
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
}
```

That way the variable score is actually increased instead of being over written.